# message signing and verification for micropayment channel

Tags: solidity, web3.py

I am writing a micropayment channel for ERC20 Token, but I have pasted here a small signature verification code which is not working.

The transaction doesn't succeeds. I have to use web3py to send signed messages to verification to the contract..

Here is the piece of code to sign message and then  sign transaction.

```
signature = Web3.soliditySha3( [ 'address' , 'address' , 'uint256' , "uint256" ] , 
                   [ "recipient address" , 
                    Web3.toChecksumAddress("contract address") ,
                    w3.eth.getTransactionCount('my address'), 
                    token ])
output : HexBytes('0xcc40a4139efd7fd5fe58396e60d18d181cee0a3d808749faa1682590ab2ee835')

from eth_account.messages import encode_defunct
## so then i sign it.. 

msg = signature.hex()
message = encode_defunct(text=msg)
signed_message = w3.eth.account.sign_message(message, private_key=private_key)
signed_message

transaction = mygrail.functions.withdraw(w3.eth.getTransactionCount('my address'),
                                         "recipient",
                                            less token , signature).buildTransaction({'chainId': 42 , 
                   'gas':700000 , 
                   'nonce': w3.eth.getTransactionCount('my address')})

signed_tx = w3.eth.account.signTransaction(transaction, 
                                           "private key")

txn_hash = w3.eth.sendRawTransaction(signed_tx.rawTransaction)

txn_receipt = w3.eth.waitForTransactionReceipt(txn_hash)
```

this doesn't work ,... what am I doing wrong?

One of the problems that I am seeing is that when I am signing my message with remix it gives a 132 byte output. But my signature is only  bytes. what should I do? But still the signer that I obtain is address(0) or in some cases a different address.

Contract:

```
pragma solidity ^0.5.0;

contract Verify{
    address owner ; 
    mapping (uint256 => bool) public usedNonces;

    constructor() public {
        owner = msg.sender ;
    }

    function withdraw(uint256 nonce , address recipientAddress , uint256 tokens, bytes memory signature) public {
        require(!usedNonces[nonce]);
        usedNonces[nonce] = true ;
        bool done ; 
        done = isValidSignature( recipientAddress , nonce , tokens  , signature );
        emit Success(done);
    }
    event Success(bool done);


    function isValidSignature(address recipient , uint256 nonce , uint256 amount, bytes memory signature)
        internal
        view
        returns (bool)
    {

        bytes32 message = keccak256(abi.encodePacked(recipient , address(this), nonce, amount));
        return recoverSigner(message, signature) == owner ;
    }

    function splitSignature(bytes memory sig)
        internal
        pure
        returns (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s)
    {
        require(sig.length == 65 , "invalid length");

        assembly {
            r := mload(add(sig, 32))
            s := mload(add(sig, 64))
            v := byte(0, mload(add(sig, 96)))
        }
        if (v < 27) {
            v += 27;
        }

        require(v == 27 || v == 28);
        return (v, r, s);
    }

    function recoverSigner(bytes32 message, bytes memory sig)
        internal 
        pure
        returns (address)
    {
        (uint8 v, bytes32 r, bytes32 s) = splitSignature(sig);
        return ecrecover(message, v, r, s);
    }
}
```